# Removing duplicates in Entourage in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, duplicate, entourage

I've upgraded 5 machines to SL and in two of them the Entourage Calendar went crazy and made duplicates and triplicates of a lot of the appointments.

I can't firgure out why, but I think it has something to do with sync'ing with ical beeing on before the upgrade.

I know it's broken in SL, but might have caused this.

Anyway, I need to removed the extra appointmenst and we're talking 3000+ on each machine (READ: not by hand)

The remove duplicate script that worked in Leopard doesn't here.

I'm thinking I'll export the calender to another Mac running Leopard and try the script there.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is this Entourage connected to an Exchange server? If so and you have access to a Windows machine with Outlook configured for the same account, try [Outlook Duplicate Remover](http://www.vaita.com/ODIR.asp). This cleaned up my calendar nicely.

(And after you get it cleaned up, ditch Entourage and start using Mail and iCal. The Exchange support in Snow Leopard works well and these apps are so much more solid than Entourage. I haven't needed to launch Entourage since I installed Snow Leopard.)

Comment: Good idea, but it's just the database. It's at an office where I installed SL on 5 machines.

Comment: I concur on ditching Entourage in favor of Mail and iCal